# Discord.js Command Input Strings

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a Discord Bot-game, and my issue is that players must create a character. However, every standard person has a first and last name, but I take other input in a single command. My issue is that I'm not sure if my code would ignore the quotes placed around the name in the event that quotes are indeed placed.

Say a person names their character Joe Shmoe. When they type in the command `p://ccreate "Joe Shmoe" Male 38`, I'm concerned that my arguments interpreter might take '"Joe' as args[0], 'Shmoe"' as args[1], Male as args[2], and 38 as args[3]. My issue is that I want "Joe Shmoe" to be interpreted as one argument. Here's my code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;
if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

If I'm right, could you please elaborate on how to edit it so that if my code receives such an issue it keeps the string as one? However, I also know that some alternatives might make quotes required around anything non-integral, boolean, etc., so preferably you can find a way that anything wrapped in quotes is included as a string, and if a string is only one word it can still be recognized  as a string without throwing the code. I know this has been done, just not how to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, here's a possible approach with comments explaining what's happening in each step.

```
/* The user enters  p://ccreate "Joe Shmoe" Male 38 */
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
// args = ['p://ccreate', '"Joe', 'Shmoe"', 'Male, '38'];
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
// args = ['"Joe', 'Shmoe"', 'Male', '38'];

/* Now you want to get the full name, i.e: the first 2 elements from args */
const name = args.slice(0,2).join(' ').replace(/"/g,'');
/* args.slice(0,2) gets the first 2 elements
   .join(' ') joins these elements separating them with a space
   .replace(/"/g,'') removes all instances of the character " */
// So now, name = 'Joe Shmoe'

const gender = args.slice(-2)[0];
/* args.slice(-2) gets the last 2 elements in the array
   [0] gets the first element in the returned array of 2 elements */
// Therefore, gender = 'Male'

const age = args.slice(-1);
/* args.slice(-1) gets the last element in the array */
// As a result, age = '38'. Keep in mind that this is a string, you could use parseInt(age) if you require it as an integer.
```

Comment: This works only if you know the number of elements that make up the string. It wouldn't work, for example, given "Joe B. Shmoe". You might as well skip the quotes altogether and just merge `args[0]` and `args[1]`.